# Update screen every hour

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, e-ink

My Raspberry Pi Pico W and Inky Frame running MicroPython works when I execute it over USB via Thonny. I'm going to remove the USB and leave it on battery. I'd like my script every hour to update what is rendered, however I cannot find much on this. Maybe it does it automatically? A stripped version of my main.py:

```
import machine
import time

def render():
    # all my stuff in here etc
    gc.collect()
    graphics.update();

while True:
    render()
    time.sleep(3600)
```

Is this the correct way to update it every hour when running on battery?

Comment: If you are running from battery you would typically want to use some sort of [deep sleep](https://ghubcoder.github.io/posts/deep-sleeping-the-pico-micropython/) to minimize power consumption while the device is sleeping.

Comment: Initialize the real-time-clock in the pico and then set an interrupt to trigger each hour to update the screen. You can initialize the real-time-clock from the host computer before you disconnect the usb if you want an exact time, or just initialize the clock to any time, the interrupt will work either way.